# A/B testing for channel preference

Tags: bayesian, clustering, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, ab-test

Right now my organization runs a lot of promotional campaign every month. We send email, SMS and WhatsApp to all customers for each campaign. I am running a project to identity the best channel for a promotional campaign. All the channels have have similar range of CTR. But using all channels for all customers is a cost to company. The aim is to reduce the cost. Is A/B testing frequenist or Bayesian the ideal method. If no what should my approach.

Comment: Your question has quite a bit of domain specific information that makes the question difficult to answer. For example, what is CTR? Also, what constraints are there on reducing cost? Obviously, running no campaign is the cheapest option but this is presumably not an option.

Comment: CTR is click through ratio. Ok let me elaborate my problem. I send campaigns to customer who have high propensity to buy a product. But I target the customers using all channels. I want to target customer from 1 channel only. Suppose a customer doesn't open my email but read my whatsapp message then there is no point of sending email to that customer. So I wanted to predict the best channel to target customers.